# BlackBerry Certificates after Moving to another PC

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I had eclipse and BB certificates (barsigner.csk, barsigner.db and author.p12) installed on **Machine X** which I used to sign **BB10** application.

Later, I moved to another computer, **Machine Y**, but didn't move those certificates, I created a **BB7** app but used new certificates to sign it. Since then, every time I update those two apps I go and use Machine X for BB and Machine Y for BB7.

However, now I can no longer use Machine X but I have a copy of the original barsigner.csk, barsigner.db and author.p12. How can I import them to my new Machine Y without affecting existing certificates that I use for BB7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest keeping them backed up on Machine Y so you can easily manage them:

- CodeSigning\

  - BB10\
  - BB7\

Keys (barsigner.csk, barsigner.db and author.p12) should be placed in the following shared folder when used by the SDK:

- Windows XP: %HOMEPATH%\Local Settings\Application Data\Research In
  Motion Windows Vista,
- Windows 7, and Windows 8: %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Research In Motion
- Mac OS: ~/Library/Research In Motion

Swap the relevant sets of keys in and out of this shared folder when you wish to use them to build either your BB10 or BB7 app.